# How to set an image to imageView using filepath in android

Tags: android

I am getting file path of  image by using browse button....after that I want to set this image to an image view using the file path

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If with `File` you mean a `File` object, I would try:

```
File file = ....
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ImagePath);
imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);   ... This works for all devices for me except Xiaomi Mi4, any idea why is that.

Comment: That doesn't work with large images in my device (e.g.: 1.5MB or 2MB). Any way to compress it (I simply want to display thumbnails).

Comment: Its doesn't set correct image size, Lakshay Sharma's answer is perfect with regarding the image dimension

Answer (score 9):

You can give a try to this code:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(yourFilePath));
```

BitmapFactory will decode the given image file into a Bitmap object, which you will then set into the imageView object.

Comment: This is the easiest method.Obviously, if you are only returning the file and not the path. use `file.getPath()` instead of `yourFilePath`

Answer (score 8):

To set an image from a file you need to do this:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg"); //your image file path
 mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 mImage.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 250));
```

When `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile`:

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }


    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
  }
```

You can play with the numbers (500 and 250 in this case) to change the quality of the bitmap for the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

To load an image from a file:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToPicture);
```

Assuming that your `pathToPicture` is correct, you can then add this bitmap image to an `ImageView` like

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToPicture));
```