# Android Q: Load image from file

Tags: android, imageview, android-internal-storage

I have a problem with loading image from internal storage i have tried this code:

```
final String imagePath = "/storage/emulated/0/dummy.jpg";
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.test_image);

  if (isStoragePermissionGranted()){
      File file = new File(imagePath);
      if (file.exists()) {
          Log.d("GalleryImages", "file is exist");
          Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
          img.setImageURI(uri);
      }else {
          Log.d("GalleryImages", "file is not exist");
      }
   }
private   boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("GalleryImages","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.d("GalleryImages","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("GalleryImages","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#63C57878" />
```

and result is:

> D/GalleryImages: Permission is granted 
> D/GalleryImages: file is exist

but nothing on ImageView,

I have also tried to load image using Picaso:

```
Picasso.get().load(file).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(img);
```

but also nothing work.

**Update**

- I have tried these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814638/how-to-set-an-image-to-imageview-using-filepath-in-android) but not working for me.
- I have tried to run code on android pie works correctly.
- I have tried to run code on another android Q device not working.

Comment: Try to use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/> ` in manifest

Comment: @Zain thanks for comment i changed permission and i also tried to give both read and write permission with adding `tools:node="replace"` but no thing showing on image view  it say **permission generated** and **file exist** but not loading image

Answer (score 0):

After too long search i have found solution [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app) by adding to application on AndroidManifest.xml :

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Hope it will help other people.